Is this long thread male without stopper to female connection tight & leak free?
I want to connect this tap (see picture) to its valve and I have to use a 90-degree elbow (see right side of the picture) to be able to supply water from the top as well as to fix the tap on the wall.

So my question is, will this work? Will it not leak? Is this considered a good connection?
I am worried because the male side does not have a stopper, like the one that couplers have in the middle, so I am assuming that it will leak.

The Tap: Link To Amazon 
The Elbow: Link To Screwfix

What's a "stopper"? Why would one leak?

I was just thinking that to avoid leakage, the male part should have stopper like the couplers have in the middle. E.g. this one

Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

This mixing valve faucet is a mystery to me. It looks like all the parts to make a working installation are not present. More information needed.

Threads seal either by being tapered and tightening against each other (usually with thread compound), or by bottoming on an internal washer or gasket. External stops usually exist for other reasons.

I see, thanks, I will try to get a washer as well to fit it inside the female elbow then

If it didn't come with a gasket, don't add one. If you do, you probably won't get enough thread engagement to not leak. Just put a couple of wraps of thread tape on and tighten it down. If it leaks, then look for other solutions.

I don't see a thread pitch or type in the Amazon listing. The thread for the elbow is listed as "BSP Female". The open question is whether they match (or are at least fundamentally compatible).
If so, it's just a matter of using PTFE (Teflon) tape or thread compound to make a seal. That shouldn't be a problem. If you wanted to improve appearance you could probably shorten the male nipple on the faucet. The connection doesn't depend on bottoming out for a seal.

Thanks a lot, so if the pitch and the diameter match then there should be no problem if I just use PTFE tape?

That's what I'm suggesting. If you find thread specs for the faucet, add them to your question and we'll reassess.
